# Java equivalent of Convert.FromBase64String Method

Tags: java, base64, unsigned

Is there some Java equivalent of [Convert.FromBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx) which

> Converts the specified string, which encodes binary data as base-64 digits, to an equivalent 8-bit unsigned integer array.

I have tried:

- [com.lutris.util.Convert.](http://www.koders.com/java/fid36571AEBB9AA7C1E039DC88B866A85348F7B077E.aspx) but it gives me signed values
- [encode to string](http://snipt.net/tweakt/gwt-base64/) then [convert to unsigned](http://www.lykkenborg.no/java/2005/03/how-do-i-read-unsigned-byte-in-java.html) bytes, but then it gives me completely wrong output (wrong length and data).

Will be grateful for any suggestions!

Comment: I refuse to give the link to apache commons-codec more than once a day..

Comment: java doesn't have unsigned types btw

Comment: correct, but I need to have same values as it would be in c# or whathever (means int 255 instead of byte -1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, chances are good that if the standard Java libraries don't have something you need, the Apache Commons framework does. In this case, you want the **[`decodeBase64`](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#decodeBase64(java.lang.String))** method from **[`commons.codec.binary.Base64`](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html)**.

Comment: thanks, I have tried both decode and encode methods but still it's not unsigned 8bit data given in result...

Comment: I don't think that's right. The output of decodeBase64 is `byte[]`.

Comment: accepted, I really had to use <i>decode</i> method instead of encode (confused by msdn description...) and add &0xff mask to have unsigned value equivalent. In such case values in c# and java are exactly same.

Answer (score 1):

The key and the initial vector are converted using `Convert.FromBase64String` in`AES` encryption in `C#`.

In java, you can use `DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(string)` method. In order to use it import `import javax.xml.bind.*;`

Here is the example program

```java
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

class AESEncryption {

    private static final String key = "type your key here.(base64)";
    private static final String initVector = "type your initial vector here.(base64)";

    static byte[] encodedKey = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(key);
    static byte[] encodedIV = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(initVector);

    public static String encrypt(final String value) {
        try {
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(encodedIV);
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(encodedKey, "AES");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);

            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());

            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encrypted);

        } catch (final Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String decrypt(final String encrypted) {
        try {
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(encodedIV);
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(encodedKey, "AES");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);

            byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encrypted));

            return new String(original);

        } catch (final Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        String originalString = "Here is your text to be encrypted.";
        System.out.println("Original String to encrypt - " + originalString);

        String encryptedString = encrypt(originalString);
        System.out.println("Encrypted String - " + encryptedString);

        String decryptedString = decrypt(encryptedString);
        System.out.println("After decryption - " + decryptedString);
    }
}
```

Comment: With Informatica the commons.codec.binary.Base64 library was not available. The solution here worked for me.