# How to define an AES key (a byte array) in both C# and Java in a "cut-n-paste-able" way

Tags: c#, java, cryptography, types

As part of a project I'm working on i need to encrypt some data with AES in C#-code and decrypt it in Java. Since security isn't a top priority (this is just a proof of concept) we are ok with the key being stored in the code as a property in some class.

The question then is: since java and C# bytes are different, how do i store the key in both languages in a cut-n-pasteable way?

This is how i do now:

Java:

```
// aesKeyBytes.length = 32
private static byte[] aesKeyBytes = new byte[]{  5, -67, 39 ... ,57, 120 }
```

C#:

```
private static byte[] KeyBytes() {
    var sbytes = new sbyte[] { 5, -67, 39 ... ,57, 120 }
    };
    return = sbytes
        .Select(sb => unchecked((byte) sb))
        .ToArray();
}
```

Is this a correct way to do it? Is an sbyte semantically the same as a Java byte and will an unchecked conversion of an sbyte get the correct corresponding byte for my key?

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with having the source contain the base64 version of the key, then using `Convert.FromBase64String` (C#), and whatever its Java equivalent is (although [according to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274925/java-equivalent-of-convert-frombase64string-method) there isn't one in the standard libraries...), to get the byte array.

Comment: This seems like the pragmatic choice that I think I'm going to go with.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Rfc2898](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt) implementation to generate bytes from a copy-and-paste-able password versus managing raw bytes.

.NET offers [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx).

The Java standard libraries don't include a Rfc2898 implementation, but there are many open implementations. See:

- [Java equivalent of C#'s Rfc2898DerivedBytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012363/java-equivalent-of-cs-rfc2898derivedbytes)
- [Java and .NET - AES Crypto Interop](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnetinterop/archive/2005/01/24/java-and-net-aes-crypto-interop.aspx)